# Minimus value given restraints

Tags: calculus

Given that $a,b,c,d$ are non-negative integers, What is the minimum value of $a+b+c+d$ such that $4a=3b=5c=15d$?

It almost seems like a part of the question is missing..

Comment: There seems to be something missing, yes. Note that $a,b,c,d$ need to have the same sign, so you can just let $a$ be as negatively small as you want and iteratively get $b, c$ and $d$.

Comment: A small change that makes it a plausible practice question is to replace non-negative by positive.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate $b,c$ and $d$ by using:$$b=4a/3$$$$c=4a/5$$$$d=4a/15$$You are then left to minimise $$a+b+c+d=a+4a/3+4a/5+4a/15=17a/5$$So there must be some other condition that is indeed missing.

I see you just added the fact that they are non-negative integers, in which case minimum of $17a/5=0$ when $a=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It can be seen that $15\mid a$ and hence $a=15k$, $k\in\mathbb Z^+$. Moreover the sum is:
$$
a+b+c+d=51k
$$
In any case the possible value of the sum is $\{0,51,102,...\}$. If $a=0$ is allowed then the minimum sum is zero and otherwise $51$.